# how do we select the parameter values to run model from the posterior draws

Tags: bayesian, posterior, vector-autoregression

after obtaining the posterior draws(N=1000) for parameters for a bayesian VAR Model. how do we select the single parameter among 1000 draws that best depicts the posterior distribution

Comment: Why are you trying to "select a single parameter"?

Comment: I am able to generate posterior draws from bsvars package in R.  I want to apply the parameters of the posterior distribution in linear  VAR to get impulse responses. I am applying a model similar to the one mentioned in  [ https://www.econstor.eu/bitstream/10419/210040/1/nb-wp2013-17.pdf  ]

Comment: Typically the point of doing that is to get a distribution of impulse responses, which you can then summarize however you want (compute the mean, quantiles, etc). You don't need to pick a single value of the parameters, and if you did you'd be throwing away information about parameter uncertainty and therefore about how precisely estimated your impulse responses are.

Comment: So I can explain the responses of one variable to a shock in another by taking any posterior draw among the N number of draws of posterior impulse responses or do I have to compute mean or other point estimates from a whole set of draws to analyze the impulse responses? which one I should do? or there's another way to explain the impulse responses from the N number of posterior impulse responses